# Building SFML project error with sf::VideoMode

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to compile a SFML project, but when i try to compile main.cpp it throws errors.
Here's the code that I'm using. It's just the template code available on SFML website. I am using endavouros and nvim if that may have any impact on this error.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is also the error message:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:6:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(int, int)’
    6 |     sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
      |                                                   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/SFML/Window.hpp:41,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:58,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:61:14: note: candidate: ‘sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(const sf::Vector2u&, unsigned int)’
   61 |     explicit VideoMode(const Vector2u& modeSize, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel = 32);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:61:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const sf::Vector2u&’ {aka ‘const sf::Vector2<unsigned int>&’}
   61 |     explicit VideoMode(const Vector2u& modeSize, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel = 32);
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:52:5: note: candidate: ‘sf::VideoMode::VideoMode()’
   52 |     VideoMode();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:52:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:43:23: note: candidate: ‘constexpr sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(const sf::VideoMode&)’
   43 | class SFML_WINDOW_API VideoMode
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:43:23: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:43:23: note: candidate: ‘constexpr sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(sf::VideoMode&&)’
/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/VideoMode.hpp:43:23: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

I've tried to directly use a vector when assigning the size of the window, but that still gives me errors. Ive uninstalled and reinstalled SFML, built sfml in the directory, moved main.cpp into build location, and still no luck.

Comment: What version of SFML are you using? It looks like that should work based on the documentation. https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.6.0/classsf_1_1VideoMode.php

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am using sfml 2.6.0

Comment: Looks like the docs don't agree with the source on github. `sf::VideoMode({200, 200})` should work.

Comment: Still getting error when compiling:
`main.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(sf::Vector2<unsigned int> const&, unsigned int)` . I'm not really sure where this error is rooted. I was building sfml projects with no issues yesterday.

Comment: That's a problem with linking. Make sure the libraries you're linking match the version of the header files. Given that the documentation wasn't updated it makes me wonder if pre-built binaries are lagging behind as well. Did you build it yourself or downlead something pre-built?

Comment: I had initially installed sfml using `sudo pacman -S sfml` on my system, but I also had built sfml from source in the directory of the program I am working on. I removed where I downloaded it from source it should still be installed on my system.